# Finding a particular solution to a non-homogeneous system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra

If one asked to solve the set of equation below with the associated homogenous system, I'd know how to do it.

$$S \leftrightarrow \begin{cases}
3x + 5y + z = 8\\\
x + 2y - 2z = 3
\end{cases}$$

$$S' \leftrightarrow \begin{cases}
3x + 4y + z = 0\\\
x + 2y - 2z = 0
\end{cases}$$

You'd find the solution of the homogeneous system $S'$ to be:
\begin{equation}
(x, y,  z) = \{ k\cdot (-12, 7, 1) | k \in \mathbb{R} \}
\end{equation}

With the particular solution of $S$...
\begin{equation}
(x, y, z) = (1, 1, 0)
\end{equation}

You can count them up and you'd find:
\begin{equation}
(x, y, z) = \{(1 - 12k, 1+ 7k, k)|k \in \mathbb{R}\}
\end{equation}

And your original system of equations $S$ is solved.

Now I've got one question: how do you find such a particular solution to a non-homogeneous system of equations. How do you find $(1, 1, 0)$ in this case?

**Another example:**
How do I find one particular solution to this non homogeneous system?
\begin{cases}
x_1 + x_2 +x_3 =4\\
2x_1 + 5x_2 - 2x_3 = 3
\end{cases}

Comment: Give $z$ a particular value, then solve the resulting $2 \times 2$ system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set $z=0$, say.  With a bit of luck, you'll be able to solve the resulting system:
$$
\eqalign{
3x+5y&=8\cr x+2y&=3
}
$$

The solution of the above system is $y=1 , x=1 $; so, a solution to the original equation is $(1, 1 , 0)$.

For your second question, do a similar thing. Set $x_2=0$. Then you can conclude $x_1=11/4$ and $x_3=5/4$.

Comment: Some times, you won't be lucky, in which case you could select a different value, perhaps for a different variable. Of course, you could just solve the system using the usual augmented matrix techniques, then pick one solution.

Comment: Yes my particular solution is wrong: I accidentally wrote 4 instead of 5 with the $y$-value of the first equation.

Comment: @Ief2 I edited my answer to correspond to the correct system of equations.

Comment: Thank you, I guess I forgot that having a free variable means that you can actually choose one freely :-)

Answer (score 0):

Find a particular solution to $\mathbf{A}\boldsymbol{x} = \boldsymbol{y}$ 
where 
$$\mathbf{A} = \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 1 \\
        2 & 5 & -2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$ $$\boldsymbol{y} = \begin{bmatrix}
        4  \\
        3  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
if we try to find 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{\boldsymbol{x}}{\text{min}}
& & \vert\vert\boldsymbol{x}\vert\vert_2 \\
& \text{s.t.}
& & \mathbf{A}\boldsymbol{x} = \boldsymbol{y}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
this will give a unique solution (for underdetermined case):
$$\boldsymbol{x} = \mathbf{A}^\mathsf{T}(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^\mathsf{T})^{-1}\boldsymbol{y}$$